# Getting 404 error when using file_get_contents to scrape html from page that has apache .htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: php, apache, curl, file-get-contents, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape rendered html from a drupal 7 site. But I'm unable to target the file with file_get_contents or curl or anything because of a rewrite rule. I always get a "404 file not found" error when trying to load any local file from my server.

My site is set up to run as a Drupal site - which is being served from a folder called /drupal3/ via .htaccess rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^$ drupal3/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/drupal3%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule .* drupal3/$0 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* drupal3/index.php?q=$0 [QSA]
```

What these rules basically do is check if a file exists within the drupal3/ folder and if so, serve that. If not, check if it exists outside the drupal3/ folder, and if so serve that. So mydomain.com now points to mydomain.com/drupal3/ however still reads as mydomain.com as it's url. This allows me to still keep the original urls to files on my server.

My problem though is although the site behaves correctly, it appears php is unable to follow the redirect rules and serve/open the final file.

`$html = file_get_contents("http://mydomain.com");` gives me `failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`

I also tried curl with CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION = true but same issue.

Can anyone give any insight as to how I might be able to properly get the rendered HTML contents of a page served from my server?

Cheers

Comment: why would you scrape your own site

Comment: Because I want to show the header and footer from my drupal pages on non-drupal pages.

Answer (score 0):

**Possibility 1**

Taken from PHP documentation: [file-get-contents](http://www.php.net/function.file-get-contents)

> A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled. See fopen() for more details on how to specify the filename. See the Supported Protocols and Wrappers for links to information about what abilities the various wrappers have, notes on their usage, and information on any predefined variables they may provide.

So make sure `allow_url_fopen` is allowed on the server.

**Possibility 2**

Make sure the server can resolve domain names correctly. Try fetching other external sites. If it's still 404 error, there's something wrong with the server's hosts file.

If both your sites are hosted on one server, you can just use `http://localhost/your-drupal-site` in your `file_get_contents`.